# Web Server OAuth2.0 authentication flow

Tags: community

I would like to login to saleforce from my web application.

1) The Web application redirects the user to Salesforce to authenticate and authorize the server to access data on their behalf.
2) After the user approves access, the Web application receives a callback with an authorization code.

PROBLEM :- Here the problem is, if i deploy web application in the local server using the callback url as http://localhost/salesforce ,It works.

But once i deploy it in a different environment callback doesn't work.

This is beacause callback url doesn't match.I cannot use a https hosted callback url because my web application isn't hosted with a https and thats because i do not have a verified ssl certificate.

I have tried self-signed certificate and it did not work.

Is there any alternative that i could use. I do not have SSL certificates to proceed with https. I am unaware of Custom URI scheme. Please help.

Thanks in advance